# Databricks Extracting features out of Big Files like Step and PDF

Tags: python, apache-spark

So i dont know if this is the right community to ask this question, but lets see.

So we are using databricks in our company and we extract Features out of big binary files like PDF and STEP. We trying to reach like 300_000 files/4h. We have a custom docker container and some libraries instaled on the workers. We now have the problem that some of the extractions are really memory hungry and our cluster workers are failing for that reason and that we dont realy know how databricks is handling autoscaling. Also we have the Problem that the Cluster take at least 5-7 minutes to get up and running.

Is databricks even the right tool for a task like this?
Is there a way to set the conditions how spark is scheduling tasks?
Is delta live tables something i should take a look at?

Soory if this seams like many questions at once, but im realy confused how the solution looks like without having like 230 workers always running.